# Want to make email is not necessary for both guest and customers in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-account, guest-checkout

I need to make email is not necessary for guest checkout and customer account creation. I can't able to find anyways. please anyone guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin for `\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification`. Update `di.xml`

```
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification">
    <plugin name="disable-email-notification" type="Module\Model\Plugin\EmailNotification" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Plugin :

```
class EmailNotification
{
    public function aroundNewAccount(\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and share full code bro.? i'm a beginner in magento

Comment: please anyone explain this answer.. :(